# Why is compareTo() behaving like this

Tags: java

I am trying to compare two strings. I am using the compareTo method but am seeing some behavior I don't understand.

```java
System.out.println("5".compareTo("10") > 0);
System.out.println("13".compareTo("10") > 0);
```

Why do both of these statements output true?

Comment: Why do you expect false?

Comment: I too am puzzled why you would think that the 2nd example should be false.  It is true for both lexicographic and numerical order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The natural ordering for Java strings is lexicographical, not numerical.  (See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)) for what lexicographical means in the context of a Java string.)

For the first example, the character `'5'` is greater than the character `'1'`, so `"5"` is larger than `"10"`.

For the second example, the `'1'` is common to both strings.  So we move on to the 2nd characters, and compare `'3'` with `'0'`.  The former is larger, so `"13"` is larger than `"10"`.

---

And:

> Why is `compareTo()` behaving like this

Because the spec says it should; see link above.   And because it makes sense.

(You would not want the `String::compareTo()` method to try to distinguish between words and numbers and order words alphabetically and numbers numerically ... and scratch its metaphorical head over strings that are neither one or the other!)

Answer (score -1):

When you provide value in ("") it is treated as String and String comparision is different then number comparision.

try below and you will know.

```
    Integer targetValue = 10;
    Integer firstValue = 5;
    Integer secondValue = 13;

    System.out.println("5".compareTo("10") > 0);
    System.out.println("13".compareTo("10") > 0);

    System.out.println(firstValue.compareTo(targetValue) > 0);
    System.out.println(secondValue.compareTo(targetValue) > 0);
```